# TryUpdateModel doesn't bind when default (parameter) binder binds correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have view model. If I put it as action parameter, default binder binds correctly. But if I create instance of the view model by my own and then try to TryUpdateModel (or UpdateModel), it does not binds. What could be wrong? I haven't found any useful exceptions or states.

ViewModel:

```
public abstract class TaskViewModelBase
{
    [Required]
    public long? TaskID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TaskOutcome? Outcome { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsOwner { get; set; }
}

public class DetailProposalApprovalViewModel : TaskViewModelBase
{
    [Required]
    public IDictionary<Role, IEnumerable<PickedUser>> RoleResponsibilities { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Detail(long id, DetailProposalApprovalViewModel test, string action)
{
    // test is binded correctly

    // binding using update model not work
    var model =  new DetailProposalApprovalViewModel();
    base.UpdateModel(model); // throws exception

    if (base.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // processing

        return base.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return await this.GetViewResultAsync("ViewName", model);
}
```

I am getting exception:

> The model of type '...DetailProposalApprovalViewModel' could not be updated.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model of type '...DetailProposalApprovalViewModel' could not be updated.

Comment: `TryUpdateModel` will not throw that exception (but `UpdateModel` will because `ModelState` would be invalid because of your `[Required]` attribute on the `RoleResponsibilities` property)

Comment: I know that, but my question is, why TryUpdateModel/UpdateModel does not bind data, when test argument is binded correctly and they use the same data and model (and RoleResponsibilities is filled by posted data).

Comment: Because `ModelState` would be invalid - your `RoleResponsibilities` has a `[Required]` attribute and there is no way that that property will bind so it would be `null` (unless you have manually generated all the html for that property).

Comment: So that means (Try)UpdateModel does not bind recursively? Data are posted correcty.

Comment: What do you man _data is posed correctly_? - the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes an instance of the parameters in your method (i.e. `DetailProposalApprovalViewModel test`) and sets the properties based on the request, and in your case, `RoleResponsibilities` will be `null` and a `ModelState` error will be added (`ModelState` will be invalid). When you use `UpdateModel()` an exception is thrown because the model would have been invalid (that method only succeeds if all validation is passed)

Comment: Action argument DetailProposalApprovalViewModel test is fully and correctly binded, so posted data are mapped to model structure. RoleResponsibilities dictionary is filled by posted data to. Unfortunately this does not happen using UpdateModel method as described above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153024/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-fanda).